# Does The Burning Scimitar allow you to perform tribe action(s) of the meeple(s) you remove?

Tags: five-tribes

In the Artisans of Naqala expansion, the magic item The Burning Scimitar allows you to "Remove two meeples of any color(s) from a Tile of your choice." This is the same wording as used in player action 2.3 Check for Tile Control: "Remove all meeples of the same color as your last one from the last Tile you moved on."

Given that it says to "remove" the meeples and not kill them, do you then get to perform the tribe action(s) of those meeples? I.e., can you place white, yellow, or purple meeples in front of you? Would you if you played the magic item during the 2.4 player action phase (Do the Tribe's Actions)?

Or do the removed meeple(s) go into the bag regardless?